# Is it possible to use glassfish with cloudbees?

Tags: java, glassfish, cloudbees

I developped a webapp which runs on glassfish and mongodb. Mongodb is supported in cloudbees, what about glassfish? (it is not listed on their website).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now full support is available for Glassfish v3. Furthermore Glassfish v4 support is added but as far as I can tell only for the "Web Profile".

More information via their blog; http://blog.cloudbees.com/2013/06/java-ee-7-and-glassfish-day-at-cloudbees.html

Answer (score 2):

CloudBees supports for GlassFish v3 deployments for web profile applications, its in early stages but in general it works. You can deploy using the bees SDK command.

```
$ bees app:deploy a ACCT_NAME/APP_ID -t glassfish3 path-to-war-file
```

You should also pack sun-web.xml with context-root entry:

```
<sun-web-app>
  <context-root>/</context-root> 
</sun-web-app>
```

See the glassfish3-clickstack in cloudbees-community github project if you are interested in how this support was enabled in the platform:
https://github.com/CloudBees-community/glassfish3-clickstack

Answer (score 0):

Cloudbees has a [ClickStack for glassfish](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/glassfish3-clickstack) - I don't know if it is already deployed on production